# disableMultipleWindows not defined on RunOptions interface for types

Tags: typescript, runner

I'm not seeing a defined type for `disableMultipleWindows` on the RunOptions meaning I can't use the runner command if I'm using TS. An easy workaround is to add this as a CLI flag; however, it seems, knowing nothing about the code, that this would be an easy thing to add.

I could also be looking in the wrong place: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/ts-defs-src/runner-api/runner-api.d.ts

EX:

```
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'disableMultipleWindows' does not exist in type 'Partial<RunOptions>'.

177                 disableMultipleWindows: true,
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks for the help!